# So i have a currency converter using GUI and i want to input the parameters from a txt file

Tags: java, user-interface

So i am programming a Currency converted with GUI.
and i need to import the currency parameters from a txt file that changes my preset parameters.

Below is the sample code i got from the question.

```
void loadFile() {       
        File file = new File("currency.txt");
       
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
           
            String line = in.readLine();
           
            while ( line != null ) {
                // Process 'line' (split up).
                String [] parts = line.split(",");
               
                // validate, store somewhere etc.
                line = in.readLine();    // read next line (if available)
            }
           
            in.close();
           
        } catch (Exception e) {
           
            // Something went wrong.
            String msg = e.getMessage();
           
            // show the message to the user!
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this the complete code? Also, is that the complete error message?

Comment: i have 3 parts for codes.
Main - Converted
Mainpanel
CurrencyPanel which this code is in

Comment: `this.dataModel is null` where is dataModel defined? Please post a [mre].

Comment: What in the world is the actual question here?

Comment: `String line; while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  if (line.trim().isEmpty()) { continue; } //blah...blah...blah }`. You don't need the `line = in.readLine();` **inside** or **above** the while loop.